# How to state some entries as private and some as public in a Strapi content table?

Tags: node.js, strapi, headless-cms

I have a table of media items (pics, videos, etc.) on my Strapi.

I need some of them to be public (all the users will be able to see them), and the others to be private - (only be visible to the user who created this media item).

So the private part is already implemented in Strapi anyway, each user can only see his own data. But how do I make some of the media items public?

I had two options in mind, but I am not really a fan of any of them -

1. Using the published/draft mechanism of Strapi. I think it is a problem because it isn't really meant for that purpose, and it could cause some unexpected behavior. Also, I might need to use the published/draft feature for its real purpose later on, and then I'll have to reimplement my public/private feature in a different way.
2. Just simply make a column at the table that states whether the entry is public or private. This idea is very simple to implement, but I wondered - is there a Strapi-native way to do that?

Thank you all!